# Get status of a task Elasticsearch for a long running update query

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, elasticsearch-5

Assuming I have a long running update query where I am updating ~200k to 500k, perhaps even more.Why I need to update so many documents is beyond the scope of the question.

Since the client times out (I use the official ES python client), I would like to have a way to check what the status of the bulk update request is, without having to use enormous timeout values.

For a short request, the response of the request can be used, is there a way I can get the response of the request as well or if I can specify a `name` or `id` to a request so as to reference it later.

For a request which is running : I can use the `tasks API` to get the information.

But for other statuses - completed / failed, how do I get it.
If I try to access a task which is already completed, I get `resource not found` .

P.S.  I am using `update_by_query` for the update

Comment: Is there a good reason to not break your query up into chunks? You could still use the bulk API, and maybe just break them into like chunks of 500 each.

Comment: Yes. So this is a update_by_query request, and I want to update a property of  all documents which have a particular value of this property.

Eg.  Every doc which has `company_name` as 'flipkart' update it to 'flipkart group'

Comment: Are you using sliced scroll with _update_by_query, which would parallelize this operation? You can also increase the request timeout value.

Comment: Yes, I am using slice as well (set to around 80% of the number of shards) and can increase the timeout as well.  However, like I mentioned in the question, I want to avoid doing it and at a later point of time know whether the query was a success or not. 

If this is not supported out of the box, is there an approach or implementation I can use to do this.

Comment: You can use the task api to do that https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-task-api but test it first. When I tried it and got the status before the update_by_query operation finished it broke my data

Comment: @alkis please clarify a bit. Because from what I tried and understood,  the Task API gives only the tasks which are currently running and not the ones which have finished running. 

Also as a side question, if possible, can you tell what happened in your case and how it broke your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
With the task id you can look up the task directly:

GET /_tasks/taskId:1
```

> The advantage of this API is that it integrates with
>   wait_for_completion=false to transparently return the status of
>   completed tasks. If the task is completed and
>   wait_for_completion=false was set on it them it’ll come back with a
>   results or an error field. The cost of this feature is the document
>   that wait_for_completion=false creates at .tasks/task/${taskId}. It is
>   up to you to delete that document.

From here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-task-api

My use case went like this, I needed to do an update_by_query and I used painless as the script language. At first I did a reindex (when testing). Then I tried using the `update_by_query` functionality (they resemble each other a lot). I did a request to the task api (the operation hasn't finished of course) and I saw the task being executed. When it finished I did a query and the data of the fields that I was manipulating had disappeared. The script worked since I used the same script for the reindex api and everything went as it should have. I didn't investigate further because of lack of time, but... yeah, test thoroughly...

Comment: Thanks. I had found out about the wait_for_completion=false param recently and it should be more clearly mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to using the task API? I have an older version.

Answer (score 4):

I feel `GET /_tasks/taskId:1` confusing to understand. It should be

```
GET http://localhost:9200/_tasks/taskId
```

A taskId looks something like this `NCvmGYS-RsW2X8JxEYumgA:1204320`.

---

Here is my trivial explanation related to this topic.

To check a task, you need to know its taskId.

A task id is a string that consists of node_id, a colon, and a task_sequence_number. An example is `taskId = NCvmGYS-RsW2X8JxEYumgA:1204320` where `node_id = NCvmGYS-RsW2X8JxEYumgA` and `task_sequence_number = 1204320`. Some people including myself thought `taskId = 1204320`, but that's not the way how the elasticsearch codebase developers understand it at this moment.

A taskId can be found in two ways.

1. `wait_for_deletion = false`. When sending a request to ES, with this parameter, the response will be `{"task" : "NCvmGYS-RsW2X8JxEYumgA:1204320"}`. Then, you can check a status of that task like this `GET http://localhost:9200/_tasks/NCvmGYS-RsW2X8JxEYumgA:1204320`
2. `GET http://localhost:9200/_tasks?detailed=false&actions=*/delete/byquery`. This example will return you the status of all tasks with action = delete_by_query. If you know there is only one task running on ES, you can find your taskId from the response of all running tasks.

After you know the taskId, you can get the status of a task with this.

```
GET /_tasks/taskId
```

Notice you can only check the status of a task when the task is running, or a task is generated with `wait_for_deletion == false`.

More trivial explanation, `wait_for_deletion` by default is `true`. Based on my understanding, tasks with `wait_for_deletion = true` are "in-memory" only. You can still check the status of a task while it's running. But it's completely gone after it is completed/canceled. Meaning checking the status will return you a 'resouce_not_found_exception'. Tasks with `wait_for_deletion = false` will be stored in an ES system index `.task`. You can still check it's status after it finishes. However, you might want to delete this task document from `.task` index after you are done with it to save some space. The deletion request looks like this

```
http://localhost:9200/.tasks/task/NCvmGYS-RsW2X8JxEYumgA:1204320
```

You will receive `resouce_not_found_exception` if a taskId is not present. (for example, you deleted some task twice, or you are deleting an in-memory task, whose `wait_for_deletetion == true`).

About this confusing taskId thing, I made a pull request https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/31122 to help clarify the Elasticsearch document. Unfortunately, they rejected it. Ugh.